# MySQL, Most efficient Way to Load Data from a parsed file

Tags: java, mysql, csv, load-data-infile

My File has the following format:

```
Table1; Info
rec_x11;rec_x21;rec_x31;rec_x41
rec_x12;rec_x22;rec_x32;rec_x42
...
\n
Table2; Info
rec_x11;rec_x21;rec_x31;rec_x41
rec_x12;rec_x22;rec_x32;rec_x42
...
\n
Table3; Info
rec_x11;rec_x21;rec_x31;rec_x41
rec_x12;rec_x22;rec_x32;rec_x42
...
```

Each batch of records starting from the next line after TableX header and ending by an empty line delimiter is about 700-800 lines size.

Each such batch of lines (`rec_xyz`...) need to be imported into the relevant **MyISAM** table name indicated in the header of the batch (`TableX`)

I am familiar with the option to pipeline the stream using shell comands into LOAD DATA command.

I am interested in simple java snipet code which will parse this file and execute LOAD DATA for a single batch of records each time (in a for loop and maybe using seek command).

for now i am trying to use IGNORE LINES to jump over processed records, but i am not familiar if there is an option to ignore lines from BELOW?

is there a more efficient way to parse and load this type of file into DB?

**EDIT**

I have read that JDBC supports input stream to `LOAD DATA` starting from 5.1.3, can i use it to iterate over the file with an input stream and change the `LOAD DATA` statement each time?

Comment: Can you do a search & replace for each table that would add in another `LOAD DATA` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am attaching my code as a solution,

This solution is based on the [additional functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) (`setLocalInfileInputStream`) added by MySQL Connector/J 5.1.3 and later.

I am pipe-lining input-stream into `LOAD DATA INTO` statement, instead of using direct file URL.

Additional info: I am using BoneCP as a connection pool

```
public final void readFile(final String path)
        throws IOException, SQLException, InterruptedException {
    File file = new File(path);

    final Connection connection = getSqlDataSource().getConnection();
    Statement statement = SqlDataSource.getInternalStatement(connection.createStatement());

    try{
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
        fileScanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("^$", Pattern.MULTILINE));

        while(fileScanner.hasNext()){
            String line;
            while ((line = fileScanner.nextLine()).isEmpty());

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileScanner.next().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String [] tableName = line.split(getSeparator());
            setTable((tableName[0]+"_"+tableName[1]).replace('-', '_'));

            String sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + SingleCsvImportBean.getOsDependantFileName(file) + "' " 
                    + "INTO TABLE " + SqlUtils.escape(getTable()) 
                    + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '" + getSeparator() 
                    + "' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '" + getLinefeed() + "' ";
            sql += "(" + implodeStringArray(getFields(), ", ") + ")";       
            sql += getSetClause();

            ((com.mysql.jdbc.Statement) statement).setLocalInfileInputStream(is);
            statement.execute(sql);         
        }
    }finally{
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826934/fast-import-data-to-mysql-in-java/34827006#34827006 Yet my question is same in case my DB is on Linux and My Java code runs on Windows then The Load Data in File query fails, Any Alternatives anyone?